# How to add Swipe Gestures to UITableView cell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, swipe-gesture, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I added this code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureR = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                             initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
        [gestureR setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];//|UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
        [cell addGestureRecognizer:gestureR];
```

it works fine. But I want `UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft` so Added like this

```
[gestureR setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft|UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
```

When I check with direction and state I am always getting 3 = 3

```
- (void)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {    

    NSLog(@"%d = %d",recognizer.direction,recognizer.state);
}
```

if I apply only one Gesture it works fine. I tried to add two gestures one by one. but it will responding for only one gesture.

How to add second gestures. I added directly to one gesture to TableView another one to cell but now use.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer* gestureR;
gestureR = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom)] autorelease];
gestureR.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[view addGestureRecognizer:gestureR];

gestureR = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom)] autorelease];
gestureR.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight; // default
[view addGestureRecognizer:gestureR];
```

If you want to handle different functionalities on left and right swipes, just change the selectors.

Answer (score 7):

**Instead of two times alloc, it would be better if you use**

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer* recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
[recognizer setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft+UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
[cell addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

**And get the direction of swipe in the action as :**

```
-(void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender 
{
    if (sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) 
    {
    //do something
    }
    else //if (sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) 
    {
  //do something
     }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I know its been ages since you asked this. 
But try and read following line again in your question. 
`[gestureR setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight|UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];`

Did you realise you added `UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight`. Twice!!

:D

Comment: Thanks. For the just record `[gestureR setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft|UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];` Works great. Tried and tested on Xcode 4.6.2