# UIRefreshControl (pull to do something) on every cell

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, pull-to-refresh, uirefreshcontrol

How do i apply `UIRefreshControl`(or something similar) on every cell of a `UICollectionView`.
I need to invoke an event when cell is swiped to left side and released(if not released but swiped back to its original position, then take no action).

Comment: Does this do what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20297813/1216830

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple uses `UIScrollView` extensively for this kind of thing.

Add a (horizontally scrolling) `UIScrollView` to the cell. Then make the cell the delegate of it.

Now you can pick up whenever it is scrolled and do something if it scrolls past a certain point.