# Swipe gesture not working in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have `UITableView` in my `ViewController`. There is a custom `UITableViewCell`. In that custom `cell` I have a `UIImageView` and multiple `UILabel`. I want to add `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` on that `UIImageView`. I have take gesture programmatically but it is not working.

Here is the code which I have done:

```
////////// THIS CODE I TOOK IN CELL FOR ROW METHOD:
swipe=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(Swipe_Handling:)];
swipe.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[cells.propimage addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
////////////


-(void)Swipe_Handling:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.direction==UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)
    {
        NSLog(@"Right");
    }
    else if (recognizer.direction==UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)
    {
        NSLog(@"Left");
    }
}
```

The swipe handling action is called but it is not going in if-else condition and `cells.propimage.userInteractionEnabled=YES;`.

When I print `NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)recognizer.direction);`
It returns me: `3`

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection) {
   UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight = 1 << 0,
   UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft  = 1 << 1,
   UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp    = 1 << 2,
   UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown  = 1 << 3
};
```

Comment: have you used  tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:   tell me????

Comment: then try to alloc init both directions seperate

Comment: you want both direction swipe?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564153/how-to-add-swipe-gestures-to-uitableview-cell

Comment: @Anilsolanki yes, if I set one direction then it is working..but why not two?I want both direction swipe.

Comment: check my answer buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code for 2 directions

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer* gestureR;
gestureR = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom)] autorelease];
gestureR.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[imgview addGestureRecognizer:gestureR];

gestureR = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom)] autorelease];
gestureR.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight; // default
[imgview addGestureRecognizer:gestureR];
```

Comment: Great  . .. . . . . .

Answer (score 0):

Please add gesture delegate method in this

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

and this line with your gesture It will work

```
[yourgest setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
```

It will work ..

Answer (score 0):

I add the "add gesture code" in cell's awakeFromNib(),it works

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
   // add gesture here
}
```